# how to ban/kick users using events in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

So I found a lot of youtube and stack overflow tutorials about how to ban/kick users in discord.py but they used commands(client.command()) not events(client.event). But all of my codes use events, not commands.So can anyone help me how to ban/kick users using events in discord.py?

Comment: Why would you want to kick or ban users via events? Did you mean you want to catch the events to send a message or something?

Answer (score 0):

Example for on_message:

- go to [events docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#event-reference).
- find [`on_message` docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_message).
- checking events fields

> Ex for `on_message(...)`:
> **message** ([Message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message)) –  The current message.

- checking field(s) docs(es) (for on_message is [Message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message))
- finding *[author](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.author)* name in fields methods if (`member`: [Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member)) not in fields else use it (member cat' be user
- ban/kick the he/she lick `ctx.author`

rst:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author in black_list: # craete a black_list for **bot** (must be Iterator)
        await message.author.kick()
```

You can change condition.

Comment: check the syntax. You are using on_message instead of on_message